# Trouble determining list size in jsp

Tags: java, list, jsp, view

I'm trying to determine the size of a collection within a view.  I'd like to not have to pass the size like I am in the code below with `.size()`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/searchAndReplace")
public ModelAndView searchAndReplace(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("content/search/searchAndReplace");

    List<Content> searchResults = (List<Content>) request.getSession().getAttribute("searchResults");
    model.addObject("searchResults", searchResults);
    model.addObject("searchResultsCount", searchResults.size());

    return model;
}
```

Within my view, when I do `${searchResultsCount}` things work fine, when I do `${searchResults.size()}` I get the error `Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.ArrayList$SubList with modifiers "public"`

I can't figure out why this is choking.  Can someone offer some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to cast it into it's object type first.

```
<%
List<Content> searchResults = (List<Content>)request.getAttribute("searchResults");
%>
```

Than you should be able to use ${searchResults.size()}

Comment: are you sure this will have **any** effect on the EL expression? You're using a scriptlet, to refer to the right type; but still there is no `getSize()` method, as expected by the EL parser. See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html#N10224) on how JSTL uses accessors methods.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, the EL parser seeks a `size` property on the object, but there's no method `getSize()` on the object. Instead, use the EL-expression `fn:length(searchResults)`. You'll need to define the `fn` namespace for that:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
prefix="fn" %>
```

Comment: How come there isn't a `getSize()` available?  What changes between the controller and view that it loses that function?

Comment: In the controller, it isn't available neither. There is a method `size()` however, but that won't do it for the EL parser.